# Does my 22.04.1 install use HD 6310 on Aspire 5250-BZ452?

Tags: graphics, laptop, radeon

I installed Ubuntu LTS 22.04.1 on the Aspire 5250-BZ452 I'm currently using. The laptop has a sticker which suggest it has separate graphics hardware, there's a grid with multiple hardware components with one of those having a square icon labeled CPU which associated text is AMD Dual-Core Processor E-350, and a separate entry with a square icon looking like a chip has for text AMD Radeon HD 6310.

I'm wondering if the current OS fully uses graphics hardware. Is there a command to find out if the OS has such integration? Perhaps there's a hardware monitor that shows separate graphics usage? Or maybe there's a test which would indicate that its much more likely the hardware is in use?

Thank you kindly for your help

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "...the current OS fully uses graphics...". AMD E-350 has an integrated Radeon HD 6310, so if you see anything at all on the screen, it is used, as there is nothing else to output pixels. There is a tool called "radeontop". You can install it to monitor the GPU usage.

Comment: @mikewhatever I have little experience, is this how to do it?
`user@user-system:~$ sudo apt list radeon Listing... Done libdrm-radeon1/jammy,now 2.4.110-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic] libdrm-radeon1/jammy 2.4.110-1ubuntu1 i386 radeontool/jammy 1.6.3-1build1 amd64 radeontop/jammy 1.4-1 amd64 xserver-[...] xserver-[...] user@user-system:~$ sudo apt install radeonontop Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package radeonontop`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want to do. `sudo apt list radeon` probably lists related packages. To install radeontop, run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install radeontop`. It is "radeontop" and not "radeonontop". To run it - `sudo radeontop`.

Comment: @mikewhatever Sometimes 1 of the 2 1st entries, Event Engine & Vertex Grouper + Tesselator, are at 0.00% while the others are higher, but there's almost-always something higher than 0%. I guess the tiny amount staying at 0% is when nothing moves on the display, including the mouse cursor. Thanks again. I wish I knew how to mark your 1st comment on this thread as the answer.